# Hibernate bidirectional @ManyToMany deletes "targetEntity" on cascade remove

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, cascade, join

in a bidirectional ManyToMany mapping between 2 entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_REGION")
public class RegionEntity implements Region {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "REGION_TOKEN", length=20)
    private String token = null;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "regions", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, targetEntity=MutationEntity.class)
    private List<Mutation> mutations;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_MUTATION")
public class MutationEntity implements Mutation {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "MUTATION_ID", length=22, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity=RegionEntity.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinTable(
            name="TB_MUTATION_REGION",
            joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="MR_MUTATION", referencedColumnName="MUTATION_ID")},
            inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="MR_REGION", referencedColumnName="REGION_TOKEN")})
    private List<Region> regions;
}
```

when i try to

```
entityManager.remove(region);
```

a region hibernate 1) deletes all TB_MUTATION_REGION rows that reference that region, and THEN 2) tries to delete all the TB_MUTATION referenced in the deleted rows from the JoinTable TB_MUTATION_REGION

this in turn causes a constraint violation exception because those TB_MUTATION entries are still used elsewhere

what causes hibernate to try and delete those TB_MUTATIONs, deleting **only** the TB_MUTATION_REGION (joinTable) stuff seems like a reasonable default behavior, and is what i'd have expected

i suspect that i might (have been)/be missing a

```
@JoinTable(name="TB_MUTATION_REGION")
```

so that hibernate tried to 1) cascade delete TB_MUTATIONs 2) before deleting the mutations it tried deleting the TB_MUTATION_REGIONs 3) then having deleted the jointable stuff it tried deleting the TB_MUTATIONs 4) finally this caused a constraint violation

so my assumption right now is that i don't even need that cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, and simply by having that @JoinTable on the region side hibernate will delete from the jointable automatically, is that correct?

ps.
i tried googling this but i couldn't find a definite answer because there are like a million other questions about ManyToMany clogging up the results

pps.
i may try this myself later but right now i am busy with other stuff

Answer (score 0):

For your desired behavior (removing a region should not delete the mutation), you should remove the `cascade` property on the `RegionEntity` class.